# How to add all objects from an s3 bucket into a list

Tags: python, file, amazon-s3, jupyter-notebook

I am working with python in a jupter notebook. I am trying to access files from an aws s3 bucket, and add the objects into a list, using s3.resource.

I have code that I believe works using s3.client, but I need to do it without client. The code that should work is:

```
bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(name='mybucket')

all_objects = s3_client.list_objects(Bucket = 'mybucket', Prefix = 'Files.parquet')
print(type(all_objects))
filenames = []
for obj in all_objects['Contents']:
    filenames.append(obj['Key'].split('/')[-1])
for file in filenames:
    bucket.download_file('Files.parquet/' + file, file)
```

What I have tried is:

```
files = []
for obj in bucket.objects.all():
    key = obj.key
    body = obj.get()['Body'].read()
    print(obj)
    files.append(obj)
```

Essentially, I would like 'files' to be the same as 'all_objects', but when I go to do:

```
for obj in files['Contents']:
        filenames.append(obj['Key'].split('/')[-1])
```

it says:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

So I do not think I constructed the 'files' list correctly. It looks like all_objects is a dictionary, and I do not know how to construct this without using list_objects. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Glancing at this, it looks like `files.append(obj)` is adding objects to your files list.  But then, you try to index the list as follows:  `files['Contents']`.  Thus, you are using a string to access an element in the files list ( and so you get the TypeError ).   Just try:  `for obj in files:`

Comment: Thank you! That gives me 'TypeError: 's3.ObjectSummary' object is not subscriptable' for the following line. Do you know why this works for the first set of code and not the one I am trying to work with?